# RxJava2.0 Observable vs ( Flowable + onBackPressureDrop() )

Tags: rx-java2

I'm migrating to RxJava2.0 and I don't quite get why it introduces the concept of `Flowables` into the API.

On 2.x, the `Observable` type no longer has support for backpressure. If your source of events can be slowed down you should be using a `Flowable` with a proper backpressure strategy.

My question is: why haven't they just kept the `Observable` type and just have you call `.onBackPressureDrop()` or similar on those sources that cannot be slowed down. This will prevent a `MissingBackPressureException`

**EDIT**

As per @akarnokd answer:

> "There are use cases, ..., where people don't want to lose data. If
>   the the data source supports a form of cooperation then stages with
>   different speed can still work together without overflowing anybody or
>   running out of memory."

I agree, but In this cases one should use the appropriate backpressure strategy for each use case. And if the data sources don't support a form of cooperation, then use `onBackpressureDrop()` to avoid a `MissingBackpressureException`. No?

> "The project management at the time decided to add backpressure to the
>   Observable type, which in theory should have been able to deal with
>   both bounded and unbounded use, but lead to a lot of confusion and a
>   never ending routine to try to educate users about why they get
>   MissingBackpressureException."

I get it, but creating two separate interfaces (`flowable`/`observable` with different parent interfaces (`ObservableSource/`Publisher`)) and duplicate ALL the operators inside of them doesn't make it any more beginner friendly. 
The reason I think it's very confusing now is because of similar sounding class/method names

- `Observer`/`Subscriber`
- `Publisher`/`ObservableSource`
- `Observable`/`Flowable`
- `subscribe`/`subscribeWith`
- is a `Subscription` the same as a `Disposable`?
- why is Flowable returning a Disposable upon `subscribe()` when 
  the interfaces `Subscriber` and `Publisher` work with `Subscriptions`. (`Observable` also returns `Disposable`, which makes sense because `Observer` and `ObservableSource` work with `Disposable`s)

Just writing this is very confusing due to the similar or identical class/interface names. They are synonyms and very easy to mix up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why haven't they just kept the Observable type and just have you call .onBackPressureDrop() or similar on those sources that cannot be slowed down

There are use cases, I guess most of the cases, where people don't want to lose data. If the the data source supports a form of cooperation then stages with different speed can still work together without overflowing anybody or running out of memory.

> is it the only reason they split the Observable class into flowable/observable?

No. The original ReactiveX design mostly anticipated GUI-like use cases or small asynchronous data sources where there was no good way to flow-control the sequence. When the ReactiveX concept was put into "real use" at Netflix, it soon turned out that unbounded flows over async boundaries put an unnecessary stress on memory and the system when dataloss is not an option.

The project management at the time decided to add backpressure to the `Observable` type, which in theory should have been able to deal with both bounded and unbounded use, but lead to a lot of confusion and a never ending routine to try to educate users about why they get `MissingBackpressureException`.

When work on 2.x was started, the new management (later on) and external parties saw the value to split the multi-valued source type into two: `Observable` for non-backpressured flows and `Flowable` that now is fully backpressure-aware. To convert from `Observable` to `Flowable` or simply create an imperative `Flowable`, one has to specify the backpressure strategy (unlike 1.x where the default support was absent and lead to a lot of broken custom `Observable`s). This is a convenience for simple source flows an one can always create a more sophisticated backpressure-behavior.

See the [wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#which-type-to-use) for suggestions on which to use for what.

Comment: Makes sense... but why create a whole separate interfaces (flowable/observable) and duplicate with all the operators inside of them? Wouldn't it be better to make one extend the other. Also it's really confusing for beginners now because of similar sounding class/method names (`observer`/`subscriber` - `publisher`/`observableSource` - `Observable`/`Flowable` + `subscribe`/`subscribeWith`... is `Subscription` the same as a `Disposable`? why is `Flowable` returning a `Disposable` on subscripton?) I had no problem understanding Rxjava1.x, RxJava two is really confusing.

Comment: Also, "There are use cases, I guess most of the cases, where people don't want to lose data": I agree, in that case, instead of using `onBackPressureDrop` just use the correct backPressure strategy for your usecase.

Comment: It is not possible because Flowable implements Publisher from the Reactive-Streams specification which is a separate library. Besides, the Flowable and Observable run on different protocols, the former includes backpressure. And finally, writing concurrent code and a library requires detailed knowledge about the underlying programming language and its capabilities; just because names match and patterns have commonalities does not mean it is possible or feasible to implement the API that way.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take your word for it for now and I'll try to become familiar with the internals of rxJava, since I find it to be hard to use without knowing what's going on under the hood. Any books/tutorials you would recommend? I'm peeking through the source code but it's not trivial. (btw I'll bounty the bounty in 7 hours)

Comment: The wiki about [writing operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Writing-operators-for-2.0) shows the deep building blocks. Also [my blog](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/) talks about RxJava internal concepts as well.